# How to take UIImage of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer instead of AVCapturePhotoOutput capture

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, avfoundation

I want to "stream" the preview layer to my server, however, I only want specific frames to be sent. Basically, I want to take a snapshot of the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, scale it down to 28*28, turn it into an intensity array, and send it to my socket layer where my python backend handles the rest.

Problem here is that AVCapturePhotoOutput's capture function is insanely slow. I can't repeatedly call the function. Not to mention it always makes a camera shutter sound haha.

The other problem is that taking a snapshot of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is really difficult. Using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext almost always returns a blank/clear image.

Help a brother out, thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Basically instead of using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer for grabbing frames you should use AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate.
Here is example:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

protocol CaptureManagerDelegate: class {
    func processCapturedImage(image: UIImage)
}

class CaptureManager: NSObject {
    internal static let shared = CaptureManager()
    weak var delegate: CaptureManagerDelegate?
    var session: AVCaptureSession?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        session = AVCaptureSession()

        //setup input
        let device =  AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
        let input = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
        session?.addInput(input)

        //setup output
        let output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        output.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as AnyHashable: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
        output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        session?.addOutput(output)
    }

    func statSession() {
        session?.startRunning()
    }

    func stopSession() {
        session?.stopRunning()
    }

    func getImageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) ->UIImage? {
        guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
            return nil
        }
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, .readOnly)
        let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer)
        let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)
        let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue)
        guard let context = CGContext(data: baseAddress, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue) else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let cgImage = context.makeImage() else {
            return nil
        }
        let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1, orientation:.right)
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, .readOnly)
        return image
    }
}

extension CaptureManager: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        guard let outputImage = getImageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer) else {
            return
        }
        delegate?.processCapturedImage(image: outputImage)
    }
}
```

**Update:** To process images you should implement a processCapturedImage method of the CaptureManagerDelegate protocol in any other class where you want, like:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        CaptureManager.shared.statSession()
        CaptureManager.shared.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: CaptureManagerDelegate {
    func processCapturedImage(image: UIImage) {
        self.imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the problem. In swift 3, the function is written in a different manner. captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) Please update your code and I will mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: @ninjaproger Why use `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` vs `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` ?

Comment: For me, here's what worked: change`kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as AnyHashable` to `kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String`

Answer (score 13):

@ninjaproger's answer was great! Simply writing this as a Swift 4 version of the answer for future reference.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

var customPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        CaptureManager.shared.statSession()
        CaptureManager.shared.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: CaptureManagerDelegate {
    func processCapturedImage(image: UIImage) {
        self.imageView.image = image
    }
}

protocol CaptureManagerDelegate: class {
    func processCapturedImage(image: UIImage)
}

class CaptureManager: NSObject {
    internal static let shared = CaptureManager()
    weak var delegate: CaptureManagerDelegate?
    var session: AVCaptureSession?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        session = AVCaptureSession()

        //setup input
        let device =  AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
        let input = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device!)
        session?.addInput(input)

        //setup output
        let output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        output.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
        output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        session?.addOutput(output)
    }

    func statSession() {
        session?.startRunning()
    }

    func stopSession() {
        session?.stopRunning()
    }

    func getImageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) ->UIImage? {
        guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
            return nil
        }
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, .readOnly)
        let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer)
        let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)
        let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue)
        guard let context = CGContext(data: baseAddress, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue) else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let cgImage = context.makeImage() else {
            return nil
        }
        let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1, orientation:.right)
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, .readOnly)
        return image
    }
}

extension CaptureManager: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        guard let outputImage = getImageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer) else {
            return
        }
        delegate?.processCapturedImage(image: outputImage)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Details

- Xcode 10.2.1 (10E1001), Swift 5

**Features**

This solution allow:

- to check camera access
- to select front or back camera
- if no access to the camera show alert with link to the app settings page
- to make o photo
- to play standard capture photo sound

### Solution

> CameraService

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Vision

class CameraService: NSObject {

    private weak var previewView: UIView?
    private(set) var cameraIsReadyToUse = false
    private let session = AVCaptureSession()
    private weak var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    private lazy var sequenceHandler = VNSequenceRequestHandler()
    private lazy var capturePhotoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    private lazy var dataOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "FaceDetectionService",
                                                     qos: .userInitiated, attributes: [],
                                                     autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem)
    private var captureCompletionBlock: ((UIImage) -> Void)?
    private var preparingCompletionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)?
    private var snapshotImageOrientation = UIImage.Orientation.upMirrored

    private var cameraPosition = AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {
        didSet {
            switch cameraPosition {
                case .front: snapshotImageOrientation = .upMirrored
                case .unspecified, .back: fallthrough
                @unknown default: snapshotImageOrientation = .up
            }
        }
    }
    func prepare(previewView: UIView,
                 cameraPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position,
                 completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        self.previewView = previewView
        self.preparingCompletionHandler = completion
        self.cameraPosition = cameraPosition
        checkCameraAccess { allowed in
            if allowed { self.setup() }
            completion?(allowed)
            self.preparingCompletionHandler = nil
        }
    }

    private func setup() { configureCaptureSession() }
    func start() { if cameraIsReadyToUse { session.startRunning() } }
    func stop() { session.stopRunning() }
}

extension CameraService {

    private func askUserForCameraPermission(_ completion:  ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { (allowedAccess) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async { completion?(allowedAccess) }
        }
    }

    private func checkCameraAccess(completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        askUserForCameraPermission { [weak self] allowed in
            guard let self = self, let completion = completion else { return }
            self.cameraIsReadyToUse = allowed
            if allowed {
                completion(true)
            } else {
                self.showDisabledCameraAlert(completion: completion)
            }
        }
    }

    private func configureCaptureSession() {
        guard let previewView = previewView else { return }
        // Define the capture device we want to use

        guard let camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: cameraPosition) else {
            let error = NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "No front camera available"])
            show(error: error)
            return
        }

        // Connect the camera to the capture session input
        do {

            try camera.lockForConfiguration()
            defer { camera.unlockForConfiguration() }

            if camera.isFocusModeSupported(.continuousAutoFocus) {
                camera.focusMode = .continuousAutoFocus
            }

            if camera.isExposureModeSupported(.continuousAutoExposure) {
                camera.exposureMode = .continuousAutoExposure
            }

            let cameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
            session.addInput(cameraInput)

        } catch {
            show(error: error as NSError)
            return
        }

        // Create the video data output
        let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: dataOutputQueue)
        videoOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]

        // Add the video output to the capture session
        session.addOutput(videoOutput)

        let videoConnection = videoOutput.connection(with: .video)
        videoConnection?.videoOrientation = .portrait

        // Configure the preview layer
        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        previewLayer.frame = previewView.bounds
        previewView.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)
        self.previewLayer = previewLayer
    }
}

extension CameraService: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        guard   captureCompletionBlock != nil,
                let outputImage = UIImage(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, orientation: snapshotImageOrientation) else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            if let captureCompletionBlock = self.captureCompletionBlock{
                captureCompletionBlock(outputImage)
                AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(1108))
            }
            self.captureCompletionBlock = nil
        }
    }
}

// Navigation

extension CameraService {

    private func show(alert: UIAlertController) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.topViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    private func showDisabledCameraAlert(completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Enable Camera Access",
                                        message: "Please provide access to your camera",
                                        preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go to Settings", style: .default, handler: { action in
            guard   let previewView = self.previewView,
                    let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString),
                    UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) else { return }
            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl) { [weak self] _ in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.prepare(previewView: previewView,
                              cameraPosition: self.cameraPosition,
                              completion: self.preparingCompletionHandler)
            }
        }))
        alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { _ in completion?(false) }))
        show(alert: alertVC)
    }

    private func show(error: NSError) {
        let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil ))
        show(alert: alertVC)
    }
}

extension CameraService: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    func capturePhoto(completion: ((UIImage) -> Void)?) { captureCompletionBlock = completion }
}
```

> Helpers

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

extension UIImage {

    convenience init?(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, orientation: UIImage.Orientation = .upMirrored) {
        guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return nil }
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, .readOnly)
        defer { CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, .readOnly) }
        let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer)
        let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)
        let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue)
        guard let context = CGContext(data: baseAddress, width: width, height: height,
                                      bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                                      space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue) else { return nil }

        guard let cgImage = context.makeImage() else { return nil }
        self.init(cgImage: cgImage, scale: 1, orientation: orientation)
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


import UIKit

extension UIApplication {
    private class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }

    class var topViewController: UIViewController? { return topViewController() }
}
```

### Usage

```
private lazy var cameraService = CameraService()

//...

cameraService.prepare(previewView: previewView, cameraPosition: .front) { [weak self] success in
    if success { self?.cameraService.start() }
}

//...

cameraService.capturePhoto { [weak self] image in
   //...
}
```

### Full sample

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var cameraService = CameraService()
    private weak var button: UIButton?
    private weak var imagePreviewView: UIImageView?
    private var cameraInited = false

    private enum ButtonState { case cancel, makeSnapshot }
    private var buttonState = ButtonState.makeSnapshot {
        didSet {
            switch buttonState {
                case .makeSnapshot: button?.setTitle("Make a photo", for: .normal)
                case .cancel: button?.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupCameraPreviewView()
        setupButton()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        cameraService.start()
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        cameraService.stop()
    }

    // Ensure that the interface stays locked in Portrait.
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
    }

    // Ensure that the interface stays locked in Portrait.
    override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
        return .portrait
    }
}


extension ViewController {

    private func setupCameraPreviewView() {
        let previewView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        view.addSubview(previewView)
        previewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        previewView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        previewView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        previewView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        previewView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        previewView.layoutIfNeeded()
        cameraService.prepare(previewView: previewView, cameraPosition: .front) { [weak self] success in
            if success { self?.cameraService.start() }
        }
    }

    private func setupButton() {
        let button = UIButton(frame: .zero)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTouchedUpInside), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
        self.button = button
        buttonState = .makeSnapshot
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
    }

    private func show(image: UIImage) {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
        view.insertSubview(imageView, at: 1)
        imagePreviewView = imageView
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.image = image
    }

    @objc func buttonTouchedUpInside() {
        switch buttonState {
        case .makeSnapshot:
            cameraService.capturePhoto { [weak self] image in
                guard let self = self else {return }
                self.cameraService.stop()
                self.buttonState = .cancel
                self.show(image: image)
            }
        case .cancel:
            buttonState = .makeSnapshot
            cameraService.start()
            imagePreviewView?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```