# How to mimic an actual 'Hardware Screenshot'? (AVCaptureSessionPreview not showing...)

Tags: ios, xcode, screenshot, swift5

I need to capture the entire contents of my app's screen (screenshot) with a UIbutton on screen.  There are labels/static images/etc. in addition to a live preview box for what the camera is showing(which is a sublayer of the main view).

I've already tried every version of `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` and `view.drawHierarchy()` methods (posted here and other places) for capturing a screenshot programmatically but no matter what I try, the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer I have in the middle of the screen NEVER shows up.

Does anyone know how to mimic the code when a user presses the two hardware buttons to initiate a screenshot?  When I do that, the resulting picture DOES have the entire contents of the screen!  If I try any other programmatic method, the PreviewLayer is always blank.

Here's an example of one of the methods I've used:

1. Create extension -

   extension UIView {

   ```
    func screenShot () -> UIImage? {

        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        let bounds = self.bounds

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, true, scale)

        if let _ = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            self.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

            let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            return screenshot
        }

        return nil
    }
   ```

   }
2. Then, function to save the image-

```
func saveImage(screenshot: UIImage) {
        
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil)
    }
```

3. Finally, run the functions-

   ```
        guard let screenshot = self.view.screenShot() else {return}

        saveImage(screenshot: screenshot)
   ```

I know many people have different variations of this but nothing I try will include the PreviewLayer (which is a sublayer of the view).

Comment: I imagine you would need to ask Apple. And I don't expect they will respond or share.

Comment: I guess you could just grab a frame from camera and merge it with screenshot. For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682698/